# Simplified Θ notation for $\ f(n) = n^\frac{(3loglogn)}{logn + 5}$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Q: What is the most simplified answer in Θ notation for $\ f(n) = n^\frac{(3loglogn)}{logn + 5}$.

I know to drop the constants to make it $\ ( n^\frac{(loglogn)}{logn})$, and that the exponential  $\lim_{x\to ∞}$ $\frac{(loglogn)}{logn} = 0$. Would that mean that $\ f(n) = Θ(1) $ since $\ c^0 = 1 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No what you've said doesn't follow. Otherwise you'd be able to do things like:
$$e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n {"="} \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^m = \lim_{m\to\infty}1^m = 1$$

Also the $3$ in the numerator is not a constant **multiple** of (or addition to) the function, so you may not just get rid of a constant in the exponent. So $$n^\frac{3\log \log n}{\log n} \not\in \Theta(n^\frac{\log \log n}{\log n})$$

Instead, just use your basic log properties:
$$f(n)
= n^{\frac{3\log\log(n)}{\log(n)+5}}
= \exp\left(3 \log\log(n) \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)+5}\right)
$$
Note that the right-most fraction approach $1$, whereas $\log\log(n)\to\infty$, so we think the behavior is like $\exp\left(3\log\log(n)\right)$. To confirm:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{\exp\left(3\log\log(n)\right)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp\left(-15 \frac{\log\log(n)}{\log(n)+5}\right)
= \exp(0) =1$$
Hence $f(n) \in \Theta(e^{3\log\log(n)})$, or more neatly:
$$\exp\left(3\log\log(n)\right) = [\exp\left(\log(\log(n))\right)]^3
= \log(n)^3$$
so $f(n) \in \Theta(\log(n)^3)$.

Comment: Note that in computational complexity, $\log$ is usually taken to mean $\log_2$ rather than the natural logarithm. (But this answer should still apply mutatis mutandis).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did my masters in approximate and randomized algorithms and I saw literally no consensus, even amongst a single author's publications. Of course $\Theta(\log(n)^3) = \Theta\left(\frac{\log_b(n)^3}{\log_b(e)^3}\right) = \Theta(\log_b(n)^3)$, so this works without modification.

Comment: Indeed I saw that in my 2nd reread @afriedman which is why I deleted my comment. My apology for the confusion

Comment: It is all good :)

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, changing the constant in front of the $\ loglogn $ would change the exponential around the final value as well? (ie $\ loglogn $ would be $\ Θ(logn) $, $\ 5loglogn $ would be $\ Θ(log(n)^5)$, etc.)

Comment: @G.C exactly, if it were $c$ instead of $3$ then it’s $\Theta(\log(n)^c)$. And obvious $\log(n)^c\not\in \Theta(\log(n)^d)$ if $c\neq d$, (which is why the other now-deleted answer was incorrect as it affirmed your incorrect reduction via constant).

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand $n^{\frac{ 3\log \log n}{\log n+5}} \le n^{\frac{3\log \log n}{\log n}} = \left(n^{\frac{1}{\log n}}\right)^{3 \log \log n} = a^{3 \log \log n} = \log^3_a n$.

[The constant $a$ is s.t. $\log x = \log_a x$.]

A. So $n^{\frac{ 3\log \log n}{\log n+5}} \le \log^3_a n$.

On the other hand:

$n^{\frac{ 3\log \log n}{\log n+5}} = a^{3 \log \log n\frac{\log n}{\log n+5}}
\ge a^{3 \log \log n\frac{\log n-5}{\log n}}$ $=a^{3 \log \log n} \times a^{-5 \times \frac{3 \log \log n}{\log n}}$ $= a^{3 \log \log n} \times 2^{-5 \times \frac{3 \log_a \log_a n}{\log_2 n}}$ $\ge a^{3 \log \log n} \times 2^{-5}$ $=\frac{\log^3_a n}{32}$.

B. So $n^{\frac{ 3\log \log n}{\log n+5}} \ge \frac{\log^3 n}{32}$.

Thus putting A and B together yields $n^{\frac{ 3\log \log n}{\log n+5}} = \theta(\log^3_a n)$.